# Is it possible to mix instance types in an AWS cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks

I'd like to know if it is possible to mix node instance types in an AWS (EKS) cluster.
I'd like to host something which requires more resources and add it to the cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed create multiple managed nodegroups using different instance types per cluster. The other alternative would be to use [Karpenter](https://karpenter.sh/) which the EKS team recently GAed at re:Invent (which allows an EKS cluster to provision capacity on a pod-need basis bypassing nodegroups/ASGs/Cluster Autoscaler.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up wiping the cluster and restarting but I'll try this next time.